# JAVA ObjectInputStream, read objects of non-existent classes

Tags: java, serialization

I'm working on an application that uses a central server to broadcast objects to all the clients. Basically a client server sends an object using `ObjectOutputStream` to the central server. This object is read at the central server and sent to all other clients, who use `ObjectInputStream` to read the objects.

All the clients contain the actual object class within their code. But the central server does not. I want to know if it's possible for my central server to be able to "re-direct" packets to the client servers.

All the objects extend the initial class "Packet", and all clients including the central server contain the base object. This class contains a simple string array containing the client(s) who will receive the packet. This is where things are confusing - I'm not sure how I'd read the packet without using ObjectInputStream to get the clients array field.

If not, I could just use JSON or standard streams.

Comment: Does the central server need to "understand" the objects or can it just treat the data as bytes?

Comment: Joni i thought about reading it as bytes, but it'd still need it to share a small essential piece of the packet - the receiving client names. I forgot to add that to the initial question.

Comment: There are many ways you could handle this. HTTP, JSON, raw bytes, ect... Either way, I highly suggest against an object stream. Your goal is to inform clients that the server has received data from another client. No need to send an entire object, which may include meta-data depending on how you're deserializing. At least as far as I know. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As mentioned by @Joni: If the server does not work with those objects and work only as kind of router, then read the received object as simple bytes. The clients still can read and interpret them as an `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Vince, i suppose you're right. My only issue with using "raw" data is being force to create an identifier for all the objects the variables sent over will be assigned to. But i guess it's time to stop being lazy and start using more efficient code.

Comment: SubOptimal the only issue with that is i wont be able to extract the "clients" field from the packets. This field tells the "router" which clients it needs to send the data to. Although i may be able to search through the bytes for this string array?

Answer (score 0):

No.

All participants in Java Serialization must have all the required classes available on their CLASSPATH, with the exception of the RMI codebase feature.